# Validate subset of a form using jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

My HTML form has a number of divs that are the steps of a wizard. Upon clicking a "next" button I want to validate just the active div. I'm using the jQuery.Validate.js plugin.

Each div has an ID, so I want a way to say something like:

```
wizardForm.validate().element('#first-step :input')
```

but this only validates the first input, not all of them.
How can I validate all inputs within a div?

Comment: There's an example at jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/multipart (currently broken due to mixed content). It's specific to required fields though.

Answer (score 29):

Taking what jAndy suggested, I created this helper function:

```
jQuery.validator.prototype.subset = function(container) {
    var ok = true;
    var self = this;
    $(container).find(':input').each(function() {
        if (!self.element($(this))) ok = false;
    });
    return ok;
}
```

usage:

```
if (wizardForm.validate().subset('#first-step')) {
    // go to next step
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I think this functionality ought to be native to the plugin. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625078/validate-different-fields-on-click-of-different-buttons-in-the-same-html-form-thr/5794770#5794770) is a solution i used in my project (before seeing this one) using the ignore option and jquery :not selector

Comment: This works great, but if i don't want to use it, then it doesnt' validate.
 
What I mean - if i use the form.validate().subset('.container') method wrapped in an IF, it works.
If i just try to validate the form form.validate(); - wrapped in the same IF, it doesn't work any more.
Any idea why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this solution and it didn't work for me. So here is how i achieved same behaviour, using jquery.validation plugin.

The validator:

```
var form = $('#form');

    // init validator obj and set the rules
    form.validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",
        rules: {
            // the rules, as usual
        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
        },

        unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change dony by hightlight
            $(element)
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
        }
    });
```

Using [bootstrap form wizard](https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard).

This is how i validate each step:

```
$('#step :input').valid()
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: How does this validate a part of the form?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the **[options for the `validate()` function](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)** one of the options is `ignore`, which by default will prevent the validator from attempting to validate any fields that match the CSS pseudo-class `:hidden`.  I used this in combination with the **[FuelUX Wizard](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#wizard)** and was able to prevent the wizard from progressing to the next step with the following:

```
$( '#wizard' ).wizard().on( 'change', function( event, info ) {
    if ( ! $( '#wizard_form' ).valid() ) event.preventDefault();
});
```