# jquery Validate Plugin Partial Form Validation in OnClick Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-plugins

My problem is very similar to this post: [Validate subset of form using jQuery Validate Pugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636512/validate-subset-of-a-form-using-jquery-validate-plugin),  but couldn't get anything to work.
I'm trying to use [the jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to do partial form validation in an onclick js function.

I have a view that has a form with many divs, each div represents a page like so:

```
<form method="post" name="surveyForm" id="surveyForm>
    <div id="pageNav">
        <input id="prevButton" type="button" onclick="PrevPage();" value="Back" />
        <input id="nextButton" type="button" onclick="NextPage();" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="page_1">
        Question 1
        <input id="q1_opt1" name="q1" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
        <input id="q1_opt2" name="q1" type="radio" value="No" />No
    </div> 
    <div id="page_2">
        Question 2
        <input id="q2_opt1" name="q2" type="radio" value="Yes" />Yes
        <input id="q2_opt2" name="q2" type="radio" value="No" />No
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit Survey</button>
</form>
```

My NextPage() js function hides and shows divs to get a wizard effect to step through the questions. This is where I want to do the validation to make sure the inputs in that div are validated.  The inputs within a div could be a group of radiobuttons where at least one selection is required or a single textbox that requires entry before moving on.

```
//on initialize I hide all page_# divs except page_1
    var curPage=1;
    function NextPage()
    {
        //****WANT TO DO VALIDATION HERE
        // Cancel page change if validation fails
         $("#page_" + curPage.toString()).hide(); //hide current page div
         curPage++;  //increment curpage
         $("#page_" + curPage.toString()).show(); //show new current page div
    }
```

How would I use jquery validator to accomplish this type of partial form validation?

Answer (score 1):

View:

```
<form method="post" name="surveyForm" id="surveyForm>
    <div id="pageNav">
        <input id="prevButton" type="button" onclick="PrevPage();" value="Back" />
        <input id="nextButton" type="button" onclick="NextPage();" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="page_1" class="wizardPage">
        Question 1
        <input id="q1_opt1" name="q1" type="radio" value="Yes" class="required:true" />Yes
        <input id="q1_opt2" name="q1" type="radio" value="No" />No
    </div> 
    <div id="page_2" class="wizardPage">
        Question 2
        <input id="q2_opt1" name="q2" type="radio" value="Yes" class="required:true" />Yes
        <input id="q2_opt2" name="q2" type="radio" value="No" />No
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit Survey</button>
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var curPage=1;
function NextPage() {
    if (curPage < 4) {
        var group = "#page_" + curPage.toString();
        var isValid =true;
         $(group).find(':input').each(function (i, item) {
              if (!$(item).valid())
                isValid = false;
            });

        if( !isValid){ alert("VALIDATION ERROR"); }
        else{
            $("#page_" + curPage.toString()).hide(); //hide current page div
            curPage++;  //increment curpage
            $("#page_" + curPage.toString()).show(); //show new current page div
        }
    }
}
 function PrevPage() {

     if (curPage > 1) {
         $("#page_" + curPage.toString()).hide(); //show new current page div
         curPage--;  //increment curpage
         $("#page_" + curPage.toString()).show(); //hide current page div
     }
 }

 function InitializePage() {
     $(".wizardPage").hide();
     $("#page_" + curPage.toString()).show();


     $("#surveyForm").validate({onsubmit: false });
 }

 $(document).ready(InitializePage
    );
</script>
```

Comment: I also found I could control error message placement anywhere in the page_# divs using:
<label for="q1" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one. for question 1</label>

<label for="q2" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one. for question 2</label>