# Validate different fields on click of different buttons in the same HTML Form through JQuery Validate Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

e.g. Say I have two textboxes A,B and two buttons C,D in a form. Then I want that on click of button C, if only textbox A is valid then form is valid, and on click of button D, if only textbox B is valid then form is valid.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ignore option.

```
$("form").validate({ignore: ".ignore"});

$("#c").click(function(){
   //$("#a").removeClass("ignore");
   //$("#b").addClass("ignore");
   $(".step1").removeClass("ignore");
   $(".step2").addClass("ignore");
   $("form").valid();
});

$("#d").click(function(){
   //$("#a").addClass("ignore");
   //$("#b").removeClass("ignore");
   $(".step1").addClass("ignore");
   $(".step2").removeClass("ignore");
   $("form").valid();
});
```

EDIT: as outlined in my comment @dannie.f post

Answer (score 0):

The above answer put me in the right direction but it didn't completely work for me. If you have a lot of fields, it would be tedious to add and remove classes for each field on button click. Plus you would have to know the ids or classes of fields you need to ignore.

This is the solution I came up with. I created validation groups using divs and used the jquery **:not** selector to tell the validator to ignore any field not contained in that group.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      section1Validator = $("#form1").validate(
        { ignore: ":not(#section1 *)" });

      section2Validator = $("#form1").validate(
        { ignore: ":not(#section2 *)" });

     $("#c").click(function(){
           if (section1Validator.form()) {
                // do something when form is valid
           }
      });

      $("#d").click(function(){
           if (section2Validator.form()) {
                // do something when form is valid
           }
      });
   })
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1">
   <div id="section1">
      <input id="a" name="a" type="text" class="required"/>
      <button id="c" type="buttom">submit</button>
   </div>
   <div id="section2">
      <input id="b" name="b" type="text" class="required"/>
      <button id="d" type="button">submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636512/validate-subset-of-a-form-using-jquery-validate-plugin) is another option, an extension to the validator to validate all elements returned by an given selector.

Comment: I ended up using [Validity jQuery Plugin](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/). Much easier to use and more flexible.

Comment: I prefer using ignore class.  You can classify group of fields using class. ie, input1, input2, input3 = class step1, input4,5,6 class step2.  on my click use $(".step1").addClass and $(".step2").removeClass.  I'll take a look at validity plugin.