# jQuery Steps plugin with jQuery validation and partial saving

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

In a Laravel project, I came to a situation where I need to:

- Make a form into 5 steps using [jQuery Steps plugin](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/)
- Validate the form on each step separately using [jQuery validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)
- Save each step on the step change via AJAX using [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

### What I've done so far

- Partial validation is working.
- AJAX submit is working.
- Partial saving is NOT working.

So,
I came across [the nice bit of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2636678) for saving partial with validation, and used it.

```
    $('.actions a[href="#next"]').on('click', function() {
        var the_form = $("#inspect-application");

        // for testing purpose, just passed the first step's ID
        if (the_form.validate().subset('#inspect-application-p-0')) {
            the_form.ajaxSubmit();
        }
    });
```

The form is submitting data and the data is saved. But...
actually it isn't working while all the fields are empty on the other steps. So, the method somehow cannot manage to skip those fields of other steps. That means the code is working on Edit mode, but not in Add mode.

Then I came across [this one: adding and removing classes to the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011945). But it actually is not working.

```
$('.actions a[href="#next"]').on('click', function() {
      var the_form = $("#inspect-application");

      $("#inspect-application-p-0").removeClass("ignore");
      $("#inspect-application-p-1").addClass("ignore");
      the_form.valid();

      the_form.ajaxSubmit();
});
```

No impact on the class (even I added `ignore: 'input[type=hidden], .select2-search__field, .ignore',`) to jQuery validation.

### Details

Code in a bit details available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mayeenulislam/815bc8af4ea4556229bb52bc41ff084c).

### Brief

Now I'm trying to add and remove class using [jQuery steps' methods](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings#example) like `onStepChanging`, `onStepChanged` etc. So that I can at least try the idea of ignoring other fields.

If you think, I'm on the wrong way, it'd be great having enlightened by any possible solution.

Comment: In my view, I think instead of saving the data every time on the server, you can do a local save in JSON objects and send the full object or partial object (as per the conditions) to the server for saving/editing.

Comment: On my opinion is a big mistake to save step-by-step the form, I would make a big form and don't store the data until the user submits the form. Specially when you are using Laravel, that helps a lot to get the old inputs.

Comment: But our scenario is that critical. Though it's like steps, but user can save partial data anytime.