# Add Custom Error Condition and General Error Message for jQuery Validate Plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I am working on an in application solution for affords me limited page real estate and therefore cannot apply contained error messages for every required field. I therefore am trying to create a solution that would highlight the affected required fields and only create a custom message for specified fields like email address, telephone and password in my form.

I am presently working with the basic shell(which is working fine for contained messages)

```
    var v = $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true                 
            },
            confirmEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo: "#email"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            confirmEmail: {
                required: "Please enter a valid verify email address",
                equalTo: "Both email addresses must be the same."
            }
        },
        errorContainer: errcontainer,
        errorLabelContainer: $("ol", errcontainer),
        wrapper: 'li',
        onkeyup: false,
        onblur: false
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: What do you need help with? The highlighting of fields in errors?  Suppressing unwanted error messages?

Comment: I really jus need to understand how to supress the numerous invalid value messages while still having a generalised message and also including custom messages for emails and any other designated fields.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is implement the [showErrors](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) hook in the validate plugin.

You get passed a map of the error messages, and then an array of those same messages associated with the form element that produced them.

Your best bet is then to just take a copy of the default handler (called `defaultShowErrors` in the validate plugin) and modify it slightly (to only show labels for the ones you care about).

You'd then have something like this in your validate options:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    for (var i = 0; this.errorList[i]; i++) {
        var error = this.errorList[i];
        //this is the only real part you modify
        if (error.element.id == 'email' || error.element.id == 'confirmEmail') {
            this.showLabel(error.element, error.message);
        }
        this.settings.highlight && this.settings.highlight.call(this, error.element, this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass);
    }
    //a whole bunch more stuff after this, from jquery.validate.js
}
```

See this idea in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/D3tfu/

Comment: this works great, but my intention is to provide a summary message for the outstanding fields and provide custom messaging for the designated like email etc. Should I be doing this within the showErrors hook too? Ive tried a few options and am yet to get anything to work. Any Ideas?

Comment: one other thing I forgot to mention in my initial question was this form is accordianised and has an additional method to validate contained areas. This solution was provided in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636512/validate-subset-of-a-form-using-jquery-validate-plugin)

Comment: Yeah, `showErrors` would be an appropriate place to generate your summary message too.