# Validate form before displaying selected bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, jquery-validation-engine

I have 4 steps to perform and validate with each bootstrap tab.

I need to validate the required fields in the first step and when the fields are valid and I clicked the "Next" button I can go to the next step (which is the second tab). The same goes for the other steps. And when I'm at the 4th step and clicked the "Proceed" button, I can submit the form and get the data of all fields in all steps.

I'm using Codeigniter, Bootstrap, Jquery and Jquery Validation

Here's my code. (**Sample only**)

```
<form action="<?=base_url()?>order/submit" id="form" method="post">
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active fade in" id="name">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div>Name</div>
            <div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class = "pull-right">
                <a href="#email" aria-controls="email" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="email">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div>Email</div>
            <div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="pull-left"><a href="#name" aria-controls="name" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Back</a></div>
            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#age" aria-controls="age" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Next</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="age">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div>Age</div>
            <div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="age"></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-7">
            <div class="pull-left"><a href="#email" aria-controls="email" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Back</a></div>
            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#address" aria-controls="address" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Next</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="address">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div>Address</div>
            <div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="address"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="pull-left"><a href="#age" aria-controls="age" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Back</a></div>
            <div class="pull-right"><input type="submit" value="Order" class="btn btn-warning"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#form").validate({
            rules:{
                name: {
                    required: true
                },
                email:{
                    required: true
                },
                age:{
                    required: true
                },
                address:{
                    required: true
                }
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            errorPlacement: function (error, element)
            {
                if ( element.prop("type" ) === "checkbox")
                {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent("label"));
                }
                else
                {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });

        $("#form").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form)
            {
                $(form).submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636512/validate-subset-of-a-form-using-jquery-validate-plugin May be you can achieve this by validating subset of the form on each click.

Answer (score 0):

Make all tabs hidden and display only the first one. Then on `next` button click do validation and if field is valid show and open next tab.

Comment: Thanks, not the exact answer I was searching for but your answer gave me the idea on to how recreate it with the same behavior